# XML Table- Parametrized Path

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a problem with getting positions of the specific node.
Problem is that positions doesn't have reference to the parent node (no attribute), but they are under it in xml hierarchy.
When I try to parametrize it in this way:

```sql
    SELECT something....
        FROM ktr_xml x,
        XMLTABLE (
            '/Invoices/Invoice[@ID="' || p_invoice_number || '"]' || '/InvoiceLine'
            PASSING x.xml
            COLUMNS line_number VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'ID',
            Product_quantity VARCHAR2 (100)
            PATH 'InvoicedQuantity',
            etc.... etc.... 
        WHERE x.id = p_id;
```

It gives me error, that string is expected, it means I cant build dynamic path based on field of invoice (ID).

If I run this query:

```
   FROM ktr_xml x,
     XMLTABLE (
       '/Invoices/Invoice/InvoiceLine'
        PASSING x.xml
```

Its getting all the items, not only from the specific invoice.

Any ideas how I could solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the query into several correlated `XMLTABLE` statements:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ktr_xml( id, xml ) AS
SELECT 1, XMLTYPE(
'<Invoices>
  <Invoice ID="2">
    <InvoiceLine>
      <ID>Invoice1</ID>
      <InvoicedQuantity>42</InvoicedQuantity>
    </InvoiceLine>
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>'
) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT x1.*
FROM   ktr_xml x
       INNER JOIN
       XMLTABLE (
         '/Invoices/Invoice'
         PASSING x.xml
         COLUMNS
           id         NUMBER PATH  './@ID',
           xml        XMLTYPE PATH '.'
       ) t
       ON ( t.id = 2 /*p_invoice_number*/ )
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE (
         'Invoice/InvoiceLine'
         PASSING t.xml
         COLUMNS
           line_number      VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'ID',
           Product_quantity VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'InvoicedQuantity'
       ) x1
WHERE  x.id = 1 /*p_id*/;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> LINE_NUMBER | PRODUCT_QUANTITY
> :---------- | :---------------
> Invoice1    | 42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b091fc67cc99d79189b3b6459a128c0b)*

Comment: ye, i get the point, i will try and give a feedback.
thanks for reply.

Comment: it compiles but it returns 0 rows

Comment: the first part is good (it returns the invoice with good number), but something is wrong after cross join, that it doesnt return any row.

Comment: Ok, i edited your query a bit, and it works like a charm, thanks mate :)